# Is there any command in cmd which can fetch updated content from git files as git logs?

Tags: git, github, logging, cmd, gitlab

Hi is there any command in cmd which can fetch updated content from the files committed to git.

my requirement is to get git logs which contain a timestamp, author, comments and updated content/lines as well.

I can get timestamp, author, comments but I can't able to find how to get the updated content as git logs(I need only the updated content/lines, not the complete file).

eg: 
file:

---

int a=2;

int b=4;

int c=6;

update to this file:

---

float a=2;

int b=4;

int c=6;

o/p git  logs should contain:

---

timestamp, author, comments, with updated line "float a=2"

can someone please help on this?

Comment: Are you aware that git doesn’t track file changes?

Comment: It's hard for me to tell from your question, but I think you might be looking for the `git blame` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though, it is slightly difficult to understand what exactly your ask is, you need to find the difference in the file content across various commits along with the commit information?

```
git log -p <file_path>
```

is one such command that gives the commit log along with the changes made during the specific commits. You can read more on `git log` command over [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

Comment: @jagan mohan Mylapuru  Please mark it as the answer for future reference. Thanks!!!